# PHP unresponding when trying to update mysql entry LEMP

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I am facing issues while setting up a basic LEMP server. While trying to update an entry via a simple way, and then if I attempt to read the database with PHPmyadmin thne PHP stops responding, but only for the specific client (I mean none of the PHP pages are working eg: index.php or phpmyadmin) but keeps serving html files (cache is disabled in my browser), restarting php-fpm, nginx or mysql dont solve the problem, I used to reboot the machine to make it work again.

I have searched for the answer for 3 days with no luck.

Im sure this will be a server configuration issue, the problem is I dont know much about servers, especially when 3 services are depends on each other, Im using PHPmyadmin as well.

I`m using Ubuntu server 14.04 with LEMP.

mysql request PHP document

```
<html manifest="cache.appcache">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password', 'DB01');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "UPDATE Site_Reputation SET number_of_visits='13' WHERE Path='index.php'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

after running this I get the "Record updated successfully" message, and PHP stops responging after I attemot the check in phpmyadmin, and the entry had not been updated (allows checking after reboot, as long as I dont update the entry again).

The error logs doesnt show anything special to me, mysqls error log did show a problem with socket file, I ran a command that tells me the path of the socket file that is currently in use. in the my.cnf configuration file I had /var/run/.../...sock and the result shown /run/.../...sock, I have changed the my.cnf file to read the socket file from /run/...

Im stuck at this point, and seems like I can`t solve this problem as long as I dont uderstand all the nofiguration files of the LEMP setup, thats why im here.

nginx.conf, php.ini and my.cnf can be downloaded from here.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkRYHTMSJ2xlgeEujQS8MVN3C-VYdw

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try running the query directly in phpmyadmin to check whether it correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I would have to transfer all the data on the server to a remote server later. I have done it yesterday with a clean ubuntu 16.04 and its working fine now.

Its not a real solution, but in my case it did not really matter when wil I tranfer the files.